# default value for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How to set default list values for Html.dropdownlistFor(m =>m.fieldname)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you generally do it:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FieldName, new SelectList(Model.ListOfOptions, "key", "value"), "-- Default Value --")%>
```